# Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Мы выпускаем практически весь номенклатурный ряд, основной акцент делаем на 50, 80, 100,150 и большие диаметры (,) в связи с высоким спросом на эти позиции.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь, скорее определительный оборот "в связи" относится к "диаметры" являясь определением последнего. Поэтому запятая не нужна. Т.е. в связи с тем, что позиции востребованы, акцент делается именно на них. Если же по контексту, определительный оборот относился бы к предложению в целом, то указанная запятая была бы необходима.